# Making Room for Second Sidebar

Tags: wordpress, themes, sidebar

I have the screwdriver wordpress theme installed on my site (http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/screwdriver)

I made the necessary changes to my functions.php file, then created a sidebar-custom.php file, and now the new sidebar is showing up in my Wordpress account, but I was told that I now need to create space for the new sidebar in the theme layout.

I am told it takes a lot of layout redesign.  Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to accomplish this?  I want the newly-added sidebar to appear on the right side of page.

Looking at what I have, I'm assuming that I'll need to extend the width of gray field that shows in the back of my theme, then move the center "plate" where my posts reside, along with the "plates" on the left that hold the widgets.  Then, I need to set the coding so that

My issue is, I don't know where to begin doing this.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Am I correct in assuming that this change will need to be made in the index.php file?

Answer (score 1):

Well it could depend on how you registered the sidebar, but...

Go into your theme folder and locate the best place to put it (perhaps at the bottom of header.php ?)

```
<?php dynamic_sidebar('yoursidebarname'); ?>
```

Refresh your site, find the CSS selector for the new sidebar, and modify style.css accordingly - you might want to float it to the right and resize the content area.

I'm not familiar with the Screwdriver theme so this may be totally wrong.